# can any one say how to install the slack in ubuntu14.04 and while trying this was the error

Tags: linux

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname slack-master: Name or service not known
rsync: did not see server greeting
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1653) [Receiver=3.1.0]
FATAL[slack-getroles]: 'rsync --links --times -e ssh slack-master::slack/etc/roles.conf /var/cache/slack/_role_list' exited 5 at /usr/lib/slack/slack-getroles line 158.
FATAL[slack]: '/usr/lib/slack/slack-getroles' exited 5 at /usr/sbin/slack line 205.
```

Answer (score 9):

I suspect, this problem has occured from the time I have installed the anaconda package of python. The following steps helped me to resolve the issue.

**Step 1**: Restart the machine

**Step 2**: $ **sudo apt-get remove slack**

**Step 3**: Download the latest version of slack from Slack website (Find the latest package here - https://slack.com/):
$ **wget https://downloads.slack-edge.com/linux_releases/slack-desktop-2.9.0-amd64.deb**

**Step 4**: $ Install the downloaded package using the dpkg utility:
**sudo dpkg -i slack-desktop-2.9.0-amd64.deb**

In step 4, we will witness the following error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i slack-desktop-2.9.0-amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 215272 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack slack-desktop-2.9.0-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking slack-desktop (2.9.0) over (2.9.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of slack-desktop:
 slack-desktop depends on python; however:
  Package python is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package slack-desktop (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slack-desktop
$
```

To fix this problem: in step 5

**Step 5**: Install the missing dependencies using: **sudo apt-get install -f**

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python python2.7
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk python2.7-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python python2.7
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 125 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 361 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,009 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 python2.7 amd64 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1 [224 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python amd64 2.7.11-1 [137 kB]
Fetched 361 kB in 0s (384 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7.
(Reading database ... 215272 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python.
Preparing to unpack .../python_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python (2.7.11-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1) ...
Setting up python (2.7.11-1) ...
Setting up slack-desktop (2.9.0) ...
$
```

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 17.10 ! Thanks.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 when using latest version (https://slack.com/downloads/linux)

Comment: I solved same issue doing first 3 steps in different order: 
Step 2: $ sudo apt-get remove slack
Step 1: Restart the machine
Step 3: Download slack and reinstall slack-desktop-4.32.122-amd64.deb
Ubuntu is 20.04.1

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're interested in the slack of https://slack.com. Don't install it through `sudo apt install slack`: this is another package (if you're interested in this other mysterious slack package, run `apt show slack`).

To install the slack of https://slack.com, follow the instructions on their website. At the moment, a convenient way is `sudo snap install slack --classic`, perhaps preceded by `sudo apt install snap`.

(don't forget to `sudo apt remove slack`...)

Answer (score 1):

```
said@said:~$ sudo rm /usr/sbin/slack
said@said:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/slack/slack /usr/sbin/slack
said@said:~$ slack
```

Comment: How does this `install the slack`?

Answer (score 0):

For me All my programs fail if installed through the Ubuntu app store. If I go to the website and manually install their software from their links then everything works fine.

Doing this fixed this exact issue for me for slack. Just went to the slack site and downloaded the .deb file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Even downloading the slack .deb file from Slack failed.

I tried `sudo apt reinstall slack` etc but did not work.

SOLUTION: https://snapcraft.io/slack

`sudo snap install slack --classic`

This solved it for me even while it was still in a "broken" state.