# How to fix slack on Ubuntu 20.04.4?

Tags: ubuntu

On my Ubuntu 20.04.4 machine slack suddenly did not work anymore. I followed the advice given [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133562/can-any-one-say-how-to-install-the-slack-in-ubuntu14-04-and-while-trying-this-wa) (main answer), but now when I open a terminal and enter `slack` I get exactly the following output:

(no output at all. I get back to the command prompt).

So how to fix this problem?

Comment: there might be an issue with the snap package if you are urgent you can go with the web-based slack version.

Comment: I see thanks. Yes I just found out about the web-based version. Reduces the urgency ...

Comment: ciao mate have a good one  @Alex

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this question][1] the following procedure seem to have worked:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap refresh slack --channel=insider/edge
```

(You might `kill` any running `slack` instances, but it will tell you). After that `slack` starts again.